# update .Append div when global variable is updated by JSON response

Tags: javascript, append

I am trying to update an .append that has a dynamic variable inside that receives the data from a web service. I get the data however how do I update the div that holds the dynamic variable? And i my case i have multiple ones that i would like to add to the .append

this is what i have so far:

```
var dynamic = ""; // global variable

var wishlist = ""; // global variable

$('#QuickAccessContainer').append(''
  + '<div id="settings"></div>'
  + '<div id="GameContainer">'
  + dynamic
  + '</div>'
  + '<div id="GameWishlist">'
  + wishlist 
  + '</div>'
  + '<div id="profile"></div>'
);


$('clickme').on("click", function (){

  $http({
     method: 'Get',
     url: "http://URL" + Userid // get favorite game list of user
        }).success(function (data) {

        var dynamic = ""; // resets the content of dynamic if loaded again

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        dynamic += '<div> data[i].gameName </div>' // generate list of games
     };
  })

});

$('clickmeToo').on("click", function (){

  $http({
     method: 'Get',
     url: "http://URL" + Userid // get wishlist of user
        }).success(function (data) {

        var wishlist = ""; // resets the content of dynamic if loaded again

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        wishlist += '<div> data[i].gameName </div>' // generate list of games
     };
  })

});
```

the problem is i guess that the DOM(?) div-gamecontainer first load and takes the variable, how would i be able to update that variable (dynamic) when the user clicks a button and the json returns the favorite list. I tried adding an additional .append just after the loop, added like this:

```
      $('#GameContainer').append(''
         + '<div id="GameContainer">'
         + dynamic
         + '</div>');

      }; // end of success
```

but in that case the .append just stack up with each click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jquery for adding and removing elements

```
var $dynamicElement = $('<div id="GameContainer"></div>'); // global variable

$('#QuickAccessContainer').append($dynamicElement);


$('clickme').on("click", function (){

  $http({
     method: 'Get',
     url: "http://URL" + Userid // get favorite game list of user
        }).success(function (data) {

        $dynamicElement.empty(); // resets the content of dynamic if loaded again

        var divs = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            divs += '<div>' + data[i].gameName + '</div>' // generate list of games
        };

        //append to dynamic element holder
        $dynamicElement.append($(divs));
  })

});
```

Comment: would this also not stack them on top of each other, when i click the button multiple times, i guess it .appends another div instead of updating just the dynamic part

Comment: it will update dynamically we are making `$dynamicElement.empty();`

Comment: i tried it but i gives and error "dynamicElement is not defined" on the line with the $dynamicElement.empty(); i removed the '$' in all of them and now it is working perfectly and indeed updates. and the most importantly nothing double or even multiple when i click the button x times. Very cool, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using global variable `dynamic`, make use of an function like `appendToQuickAccessContainer` and pass the `children` of the target `div` as string. Then inside the function do the dom operation. It is more clean and safe. Here is how I'd do it.

```js
function appendToQuickAccessContainer(children) {
  var $quickAccessContainer = $('#QuickAccessContainer');
  var $gameContainer;

  if ($quickAccessContainer.children('div#GameContainer').length === 0) {
    $gameContainer = $quickAccessContainer.append($("<div/>", {
      id: 'GameContainer'
    }));
  } else {
    $gameContainer = $quickAccessContainer.find("#GameContainer");
  }
  $gameContainer.append(children);
}

$('.clickme').on("click", function() {

  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/"
  }).done(function(data) {
    var domString = "";
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      domString += '<div>' + data[i].title + '</div>';
    }

    appendToQuickAccessContainer(domString);
  })

});


$('.anthoer-clickme').on("click", function() {

  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
  }).done(function(data) {
    var domString = "";
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      domString += '<div>' + data[i].email + '</div>';
    }

    appendToQuickAccessContainer(domString);
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="QuickAccessContainer">
</div>
<button class='clickme'>
    Click Me
    </button>

<button class='anthoer-clickme'>
    Click Another
    </button>
```

Comment: thanks, this seems to work but how would i do it if i have another list as well that i get in the same way? - i updated my question

Comment: You mean adding inside the `GameContainer` div?

Comment: it still seems they just stack up, the quickAccesContainer each time when i click get's and additional GamesList, it add's it does not replace, it's the same as the example i made in the question in the end.

Comment: @EwaldBos I updated the code. For any new question now, open a new question. Editing the question and then ask for code tweak is not a good idea. Always ask a new question for a new problem. thanks